# How do I remove parts from my 3d printing file?

Tags: 3d-printing

I have purchased a 3d model online in the form of stl files.
It all printed really well apart from one part. The hook shaped part at the front of the image.
[image]
I can't work out how to delete the other three objects from the file so I can print out only the part I need. 
I've tried selecting in edit and deleting but it seems to leave a cloud of undeleted bits.
Any help would be much appreciated!
Rob

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange ! Can you send the blend file is possible?

Comment: Thanks! How do I add files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- select vertex of part you want to keep
- select linked by <kbd>L</kbd>
- invert selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>
- delete <kbd>X</kbd>

Comment: That's great! Thanks!